# Aligning buttons in CSS/HTML in one line horizontally w/ text?

Tags: html, css

I would like to know how could I align my buttons horizontally? On top of that I want to add text to those buttons. This is what I currently have.

HTML body part:

```
<body> 
    <div class="tile_div">
        <table class="tile_table">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img class="tile_image" height="50px" width="100px" src="./images/button_left.png"/> 
                    <p class="tile_p">Button one</p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <img class="tile_image" height="50px" width="100px" src="./images/button_left.png"/> 
                    <p class="tile_p">Button two</p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <img class="tile_image" height="50px" width="100px" src="./images/button_left.png"/> 
                    <p class="tile_p">Button three</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.tile_image {
    float: left;
    margin: 0px;
}

.tile_image img {
    position:absolute;
}

.tile_p {
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
}
```

How it looks like:
http://img580.imageshack.us/img580/8867/uo7i.png

I want the text to be in the middle of the buttons not below them.

**EDIT:**

Alright so when I use
`src="./images/button_left.png"` the image looks they way it should look:

```html
http://img580.imageshack.us/img580/8867/uo7i.png
```

But when ever I use background-image
This happens:
http://img580.imageshack.us/img580/6127/yz4.png

Comment: the "buttons" should not be clickable?

Comment: they should be clickable, I'm new with html&css.

Comment: Have a look at my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17629788/aligning-buttons-in-css-html-in-one-line-horizontally-w-text/17629849#17629849

Answer (score 8, accepted):

tables should not be used for layout. I think the best approach would be to use floated links like this:

```
<div class="tile_div">
    <a href="#">Button one</a>
    <a href="#">Button two</a>
    <a href="#" class="last">Button three</a>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.tile_div a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    background-image: url(./images/button_left.png);
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.title_div a.last {
    margin-right: 0;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fx4Qd/2/)

Comment: Added a JSFiddle. Also, `line-height: 50px`? Why not use padding-top?

Comment: width padding-top the height must be recalculated. `line-height` is a better way to align the text vertically.

Comment: Oh, cool. Well, unless a two-line caption would be needed, but this design doesn't seem to indicate that such flexibility is intended.

Comment: I think is best remove float and add display: inline-block!

Comment: @exizt yes two-line caption would be a problem. but you could add a class to each button and adjust the line-height/padding.

Comment: @RiccardoPasianotto and what do you do with IE7?

Comment: @RiccardoPasianotto and the whitespace between links? no I think floating is the way to go.

Comment: Remove also margin-right and the whitespace go away. Anyway relax man, [here](http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_explorer.asp) there are only 0,8% of 12% that use IE7

Comment: @RiccardoPasianotto no I mean with `inline-block` you'll always face the problem of whitespace between elements. And even 0.1% could be millions of people. It depends on the traffic of the site. And I don't like to use browser hacks if there is a better way.

Comment: Well.. this is what it looks like http://img580.imageshack.us/img580/6127/yz4.png

Comment: @John ok but these are different images than in the first example?!

Comment: No, they're not different, they're the same with the first one. By making it background image it turns into that.

Comment: @john then the images are not 100x50. You should scale them to 100x50px in your favorite paint application.

Comment: Yeah, I had to change the actual button.png size, not just the height,width in css. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok you need to exchange the `img` and the `p` with this:

```
<button style="background: url('./images/button_left.png'); width: 100px; height: 50px; border: 0;">Button one</button>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6duRf/

Comment: Didnt help as much, as I'm getting this now http://img580.imageshack.us/img580/6127/yz4.png

Comment: can you give me a link to the  images you are using as a background

Comment: You didn't set the background-size here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6duRf/2/