# Mixing in jQuery's UI widget with my topNav kills horizontal alignment

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

In my web application using jQuery and jQuery UI (1.10.2 and 1.10.4 respectively), I use the CSS in jQuery CSS in `/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.css` of the zip file from the jQuery site. I had a topNav bar like so before I got the jQuery-based autocomplete function to work:

```
MyProfile         Link1          Link2      |   search box           |     Logout
```

My search box is 300px and my fonts are 12px, and the width of the `div` container above is `700px` and BEFORE I added jQuery autocomplete support, it was something like this:

```
<div class="topNav">
    <div class="left">
          <a href...>MyProfile</a>>&nbsp&nbsp
          <a href...>Link1</a>>&nbsp&nbsp
          <a href...>Link2</a>>&nbsp&nbsp
    </div>
    <input id="searchBox" name="searchBox" type="search" >
    <div class="right">
          <a href...>Logout</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

It was all well aligned then (all of `topNav` in one line).

Now, after adding jQuery support like so:

```
<div class="topNav">
    <div class="left">
          <a href...>MyProfile</a>>&nbsp&nbsp
          <a href...>Link1</a>>&nbsp&nbsp
          <a href...>Link2</a>>&nbsp&nbsp
    </div>

     <!-- div-ing the input searchBox was the only change: -->
     <div class="ui-widget">
           <input id="searchBox" name="searchBox" type="search" >
     </div>


    <div class="right">
          <a href...>Logout</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And now, the search box has decided it will appear in the next line, and the Logout also appears in the second line, like so:

```
MyProfile         Link1          Link2      
 |   search box           |                                                  Logout
```

Any help on how to horizontally align after jQuery autocomplete support is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the approach in the accepted answer in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17629788/aligning-buttons-in-css-html-in-one-line-horizontally-w-text). That seems to have solved my problem. The CSS properties of `.ui-widget` (the jQuery div element) can be additionally changed (for font size etc.) in your application, that is another way you can remove the issues from including that dependency.