# How to put multiple submit buttons inline in a form in Symfony 5?

Tags: forms, button, inline, symfony5

I'm trying to create a form with 3 submit buttons and I want to put them horizontally at the bottom of the form.

I created my form:

```php
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
    ->add('title', CKEditorType::class, [
        'label'=>'Title'
    ])
    ->add('content', CKEditorType::class, [
        'label'=>'Content'
    ])
    ->add('save', SubmitType::class, [
        'label' => 'Save'
    ])
    ->add('saveAndQuit', SubmitType::class, [
        'label' => 'Save and quit'
    ])
    ->add('quit', SubmitType::class, [
        'label' => 'Quit'
    ]);
}
```

The three buttons are aligned vertically.

How I could align them horizontally ?

Answer (score 1):

To align the buttons you can try the 'attr' attribute when building your form.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
    ->add('title', CKEditorType::class, [
        'label'=>'Title',
        'attr' => ['class' => 'your_class']
    ])
}
```

Then you can add the css properties to that class.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer.
I don't know how to horizontally align 3 buttons in CCS without having access to parent element, can you help me?

Comment: That depends on what you're using, if it's pure CSS or you have Bootstrap etc...

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_flex.asp

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17629788/aligning-buttons-in-css-html-in-one-line-horizontally-w-text